# Python AWS function error :module initialization error name 'tz' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda

I am Trying to run a python code using AWS function,I have added .zip folder with all dependency and proper structure but gettiing below error .
But when executing same code with Node js working fine .

```
 import pytz 
 import urllib3
 import calendar
 def lambda_handler(event, context):

       tz=pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
 utc = datetime.utcnow() 
 utc = pytz.utc.localize(utc, is_dst=None).astimezone(tz)
 time =  utc.strftime("%H") # gmt/utc time
 text = ""
 textaum = ""


Function Logs:
START RequestId: c5f433f7-2a61-11e8-9d30-b9dad0fd99997 Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: name 'tz' is not defined
```

Comment: you need to properly indent the contents of your lambda_handler function

Answer (score 0):

It is all with the scope of the variable, you have the variable tz in function definition, outside that it is not accessible ...

Plus you have a lot of errors in your code say for example datetime is not defined so you need to import the datetime module, please correct them as well